# Passing R variables to a python script with reticulate

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I have a python script that I want to run from within R using the reticulate package. I want to assign some variables in R first, and then pass them to the script. Unfortunately when I run the script, I am surprised to see that python can't recognize the variables. What am I missing here? Thanks

Python script (`test.py`):

```
print(x)
```

R code:

```
library(reticulate)
x <- 5
source_python(test.py)
```

The error:

```
Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : 
  NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: Try: python_run_string("x = 5"); source_python("test.py");
Unfortunately, source_python can only set variables to your R session. It does not read variables unless they are from python code that has been evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I came up with was to just create a function. So if before my python code was

```
z = x + 3
```

My new python code would be:

```
def add_three(x):
    z = x + 3
    return z
```

and then I can, in R run:

```
x <- 5
source_python("test.py")
y <- add_three(x)
```

and get y as 6.

Comment: As exactly what the [docs](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/) show.

Comment: It does work. However, u passed the parameter to a function to python code. If it means that if one what to pass parameters to a python script, he should call a function? Sometimes, It may not be convenient. Can python script access variables from R code above？