# How can I call R script with passing parameters from Python?

Tags: python, r, parameter-passing, rpy2

I call R script from Python as follows:

```
 import rpy2.robjects as robjects
 robjects.r.source("C:\\Users\Name\Documents\compbdt.R", encoding="utf-8")
```

And my R script is below:

```
main <- function(N) {
  require(data.table)
  data <- fread("C:\\compbdt.csv", sep=",")
  for (i in 1:N) {
    s11 <- data[i, s11]
    s10 <- data[i, s10]
    s01 <- data[i, s01]
    s00 <- data[i, s00]
    r11 <- data[i, r11]
    r10 <- data[i, r10]
    r01 <- data[i, r01]
    r00 <- data[i, r00]
    
    compbdt(s11, s10, s01, s00, r11, r10, r01, r00)
  }
}

main(N)
```

`compbdt` is a function as well, I just haven't shown it there.

I need `main` function to loop `N` times. `N` is defined during Python code.

How can I pass `N` as an argument to call R script properly?

Comment: This might be what along the lines of what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526092/passing-r-variables-to-a-python-script-with-reticulate

Comment: It offers "call Python from R" while I need exactly the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `reticulate` package. Run your Python code in either an R Markdown file or source it using `reticulate::source_python()`. This creates a Python object *in your R session* called `py`. Access objects created in Python using the extract operator: `py$N`, for example, would correspond with an object named `N` created by your Python script.

```
library(reticulate)
```

```
# This is a python block
N = 2
```

```
# This is an R block
r_N <- py$N
main(r_N)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).